# Unable to get tokens for app using code from azure graph

Tags: php, azure-ad-b2c, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I have created an app in http://apps.dev.microsoft.com/ and tried to connect from my web application
**Here is my code:**

```
  $data = array (
          'code' => $code,
          'client_secret' => 'C2A32632155A3270220244A5774431C58126F9B5',
          'client_id' => '49c1c823-b423-4673-af57-7be1ab39e386',
          'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
          'redirect_uri' => 'http://localhost/crm/contacts/connectOffice',
          'scope' => 'offline_access Contacts.ReadWrite'
        );
    $url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token';
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);      
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);  
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
```

**I get the response :**

> [error] => invalid_client
>       [error_description] => AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials. AADSTS50012: Invalid client secret is provided. Trace ID:
>   47f5eaa3-2ea0-45bc-9bfa-8457395ae354 Correlation ID:
>   3007e67d-120d-4cf1-a0e6-1863d202b233 Timestamp: 2017-01-12 13:12:28Z
>       [error_codes] => Array
>           (
>               [0] => 70002
>               [1] => 50012
>           )
>
> ```
> [timestamp] => 2017-01-12 13:12:28Z
> [trace_id] => 47f5eaa3-2ea0-45bc-9bfa-8457395ae354
> [correlation_id] => 3007e67d-120d-4cf1-a0e6-1863d202b233
> ```

I am quite sure that I have provided the correct client secret and client Id in the request but still I get this error all the time . Can anyone suggest where I may be going wrong or what more do I need to do to correct this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value you're using in your client secret field right now is actually a Public Key that is generated if you hit the `Generate New Key Pair` button.

For what you're trying to do, you'll want to hit the `Generate New Password` button in the portal to get a 23 character client secret. That should allow you to get an auth code.

One other thing, make sure if you're trying to get an auth code you use the correct authorization endpoint `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize`.  The url you have above is used when you have an auth code and want to exchange it for tokens.

Comment: I do have the authorization code @Daniel Dobalian  andI am trying to get the tokens

Comment: Did using the `Generate New Password` secret fix your error?